# catch exceptions in phpoffice with docx

Tags: php

How to catch this exception (or any exception in phpoffice)

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/master/src/PhpWord

```
require_once \Ini::get('path/class').'/third-party/phpword/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererPath(\Ini::get('path/class').'/third-party/tcpdf');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings::setPdfRendererName('TCPDF');

try{
    $word = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file_dst);
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($word, 'PDF');
}
catch(\PhpOffice\PhpWord\BadMethodCallException $e){

}
```

## error

```
    PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Cannot add PreserveText in Cell.' in /var/www/dyntest.dk/class/third-party/phpword/Element/AbstractContainer.php:276
```

Comment: Have you tried catching it in the normal way? Did that not work? See here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: yes.. have updated my question - and it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats a [base PHP Exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php) (part of the PHP core, not PHPOffice), you should catch it like this:

```
try{
    $word = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::load($file_dst);
    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($word, 'PDF');
}
catch(\BadMethodCallException $e){

}
```